# RabbitMQ multiple consumers with one queue, messages getting stuck

Tags: python, rabbitmq

In RabbitMQ, I have a single queue and two consumers ready to run messages.

Some messages are heavy and take several minutes to complete, others are very quick and will finish within a second.

Currently, RabbitMQ just round robins the consumers to deliver messages to, which is annoying because sometimes I end up with this scenario:

- Rabbit sends a low priority HEAVY-1 payload to worker 1 and it gets blocked for several minutes
- Rabbit sends a high priority LIGHT-2 payload worker 2 and completes immediately
- Rabbit sends a high priority LIGHT-3 payload to worker 1 and it gets queued as worker 1 is still busy processing the HEAVY-1 payload, worker 2 is sitting there doing nothing and LIGHT-3 payload is stuck waiting for HEAVY-1 to complete, when it could have been processed by worker 2 already.

How do I design my RabbitMQ structure to prevent this scenario? I was thinking along the lines of a solution where I send all the heavy payloads to worker-1 and all the light payloads to worker-2 so they are never delayed.  However, I am not sure the best way to do this, e.g. should I use two queues?

I program in Python so any code samples in that would be useful.

Comment: I have been working with RabbitMQ and Python since last 4 years. And I think even in Round Robin distribution if `consumer 1` doesn't sends the acknowledgement then message will goes into the `consumer 2`. But make sure that prefetch count is set to `1` only. And If you are still facing this issue then two different queue approach is also a good one if you can tell that which message will take more time and which one will less.